# Chaining command with wait functionality

Tags: go

I have the following code which works, I need to execute commands in chain that need to finish before the other command is executed.
I do it with the wait command with ugly `ifElse` and if I need to chain more command it become uglier...is there a better way to write it in go?

```
    cmd, buf := exec.CommandContext("npm", dir+"/"+path, "install")

    //Wait 
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("executing npm install returned error: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Println(buf.String())
        gulpCmd, gulpBuf := exec.CommandContext(“gulp”, pdir+"/"+n.path)
   //Wait 
        if err := gulpCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        } else {
            log.Println(gulpBuf.String())
            pruneCmd, pruneBuf := exec.CommandContext("npm", pdir+"/"+n.path, "prune", "--production")
     //Wait 
            if err := pruneCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
            } else {
                log.Println(pruneBuf.String())
            }

        }
```

**update:**

if I try to run this simple program it works and I get message

```
added 563 packages in 19.218s*
```

This is the code

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")
cmd.Dir = filepath.Join(pdir, n.path)
cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
}
fmt.Print(string(cmdOutput.Bytes()))
```

But If I try like following, I get error and it not able to execute the first command which is npm install, any idea?

```
cmdParams := [][]string{
    {"npm", filepath.Join(dir,path), "install"},
    {"gulp", filepath.Join(pdir,n.path)},
    {"npm", filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "prune", "--production"},
}

for _, cmdParam := range cmdParams {
    out, err := exec.Command(cmdParam[0], cmdParam[1:]...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error running %s: %v\n", cmdParam[0], err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(string(out))
}
```

The error I get is **error running npm: exit status 1**

**update 2**

The commands are and should be run one after another, when the first finish just then run the gulp etc, and also I need to provide the output from the commands

```
1. npm install
2. gulp
3. npm prune
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List your commands in a slice, and use a simple loop to execute all sequentially. And use [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) to build folders.

Also I'm not sure what package you're using to run the commands, using [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) we can simplify further the execution of the commands in the loop body. For example [`Command.Output()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) runs the command and returns its standard output:

```
cmdParams := [][]string{
    {filepath.Join(dir,path), "npm", "install"},
    {filepath.Join(pdir,n.path), "gulp"},
    {filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "npm", "prune", "--production"},
}

for _, cp := range cmdParams {
    log.Printf("Starting %s in folder %s...", cp[1:], cp[0])
    cmd := exec.Command(cp[1], cp[2:]...)
    cmd.Dir = cp[0]
    // Wait to finish, get output:
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Finished %s, output: %s", cp[1:], out)
}
```

Comment: I try to use the code and I got multiple errors , will try with the last update like on `cmdParams` etc as unused

Comment: wnen I use the code I got lots of error like in unused `cmdParams` and also where is the `wait` ?

Comment: @RaynD Then you failed to copy my code. `cmdParams` is used in the loop. And wait is not needed since `Command.Outupt()` implicitly waits for the command to complete (or fail).

Comment: I was able to fix the error it should be like this missing trailing `,` ` `cmdParams := [][]string{
  {"npm", filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "install"},
  {"gulp", filepath.Join(pdir, n.path)},
  {"npm", filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "prune", "--production"},
 }

 for _, cmdParam := range cmdParams {
  out, err := exec.Command(cmdParam[0], cmdParam[1:]...).Output()
  if err != nil {
   log.Printf("error running %s: %v\n", cmdParam[0], err)
   return err
  }
  log.Println(string(out))
 }`

Comment: @RaynD You're right, the code I've posted had syntax error. Fixed it.

Comment: Great, ive test it now and I got error `could not find symbol value for Stderr` when running `npm install` any idea what it could be ?

Comment: @RaynD I just copied the commands from the question, are you sure they are valid and working?

Comment: the command that I run is wrapper on os/exec like this and it works , not im not sure why the error is coming and in the debug the second paramter show the right path, any idea what it could be ?...`func CommandContext(name string, entryPath string, args ...string) (*exec.Cmd, *bytes.Buffer) {

 cmd := exec.Command(name, args...)
 cmd.Dir = entryPath
 buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
 cmd.Stdout = buf
 cmd.Stderr = buf
 if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
  log.Printf("Failed to start cmd: %v", err)
 }
 return cmd, buf
}`

Comment: Did you check it on your side with npm ?

Comment: I try again to use the code you suggested, which is look exactly what I want but it's not working...failing on the first command, please see my update. do I miss something ? becouse running `npm install` with the regular exec works...

Comment: the error I got is `error running npm: exit status 1` and using the simple `cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")` works...

Comment: maybe its related to this ? `cmdParam[1:]...` ,?

Comment: @RaynD You claim `exec.Command("npm", "install")` works, but the first command you execute is `exec.CommandContext("npm", dir+"/"+path, "install")`, they are not the same. Please edit the question and list the exact commands you would run in your shell, and I'll edit my Go code to match those.

Comment: To make it more clear ignore `commandContext` and assume Im using the code in the update which is more generic and works( the `CommandContect` is just wrapper of the `exec.Command` ...) and the are doing at the end exactly the same...

Comment: You can create this simple pacage json and try to run your code...you will see the error which I get https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @RaynD Regardless of any Go code, can you list all the shell commands you want to execute?

Comment: exactly like in the post    `{"npm", filepath.Join(dir,path), "install"},
    {"gulp", filepath.Join(pdir,n.path)},
    {"npm", filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "prune", "--production"},`

Comment: @RaynD Ok, so the folder is the working directory, and it's not a parameter of the commands. See my edited answer.

Comment: I try it and now there is error to compile the code , it doesn't recognise `exec.Output()` , should I get the output differently?

Comment: It should be `cmd.Output()` , Thanks!

Comment: one last question in this context, assume I need to add to the out message `string(out) ` additional info which related to each process, how would you do it ? for example, `starting npm install` and `done running npm install` , thanks a lot!

Comment: @RaynD See edited answer. Added logs to display which command in which folder is being executed.

Comment: please see if you can help here either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849625/running-command-and-get-the-output-online   , thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ugly `if-else` you can write code like this:

```
err := someFunction1()
if err != nil {
  return err
}

err := someFunction2()
if err != nil {
  return err
}

err := someFunction3()
if err != nil {
  return err
}
```

but you will have ugly (IMHO) multiply `return` statements

Comment: Your opinion is fine but it's worth noting that multiple returns is 100% idiomatic Go. It is the preferred method for handling this type of logic in this language.

Comment: @Adrian yeah, but it still seems to me ugly :-)