# Running command and get the output online

Tags: go

I use the following code which works, The problem is that the output is printed just as the process finished to execute,
I want to print to the screen the output live and not provide all the output when the process finishes, how can I achieve this?

```
cmdParams := [][]string{
    {filepath.Join(dir,path), "npm", "install"},
    {filepath.Join(pdir,n.path), "gulp"},
}

for _, cp := range cmdParams {
    log.Printf("Starting %s in folder %s...", cp[1:], cp[0])
    cmd := exec.Command(cp[1], cp[2:]...)
    cmd.Dir = cp[0]
    // Wait to finish, get output:
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Finished %s, output: %s", cp[1:], out)
}
```

**update** when trying the proposed solution I got the output like

```
2018/02/18 11:11:57  Starting [npm install] in folder ...
2018/02/18 11:12:14 adde
2018/02/18 11:12:14 d 56
2018/02/18 11:12:14 3 pa
2018/02/18 11:12:14 ckag
2018/02/18 11:12:14 es i
2018/02/18 11:12:14 n 15
2018/02/18 11:12:14 .477
2018/02/18 11:12:14 s
2018/02/18 11:12:14 Finished %s [npm install]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming commands output progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725751/streaming-commands-output-progress/30726590#30726590). Also see related: [How to get the realtime output for a shell command in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091316/how-to-get-the-realtime-output-for-a-shell-command-in-golang/37137583#37137583)

Comment: @icza - so I should use `oneByte := make([]byte, 1)
for {
    _, err := stdout.Read(oneByte)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf("%c", oneByte[0])
}` for this case ? if so where ? it's a bit confusing ...

Comment: Use the solution from the accepted answer of the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @icza - do you mean -`scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)` ?

Comment: @icza - it will be great if you can provide example with my context, since I read the post and it's difference , I run several command and I use the `cmd.Output()` which I dont understand how to relate them...

Comment: See my answer below. I haven't tested it, but hopefully it works right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the solution presented in this answer: [Streaming commands output progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725751/streaming-commands-output-progress/30726590#30726590)

```
cmdParams := [][]string{
    {filepath.Join(dir, path), "npm", "install"},
    {filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "gulp"},
}
for _, cp := range cmdParams {
    log.Printf("Starting %s in folder %s...", cp[1:], cp[0])
    cmd := exec.Command(cp[1], cp[2:]...)
    cmd.Dir = cp[0]

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%s cmd.StdoutPipe() error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }
    // Start command:
    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%s start error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }

    // Stream command output:
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanner.Text())
    }
    if scanner.Err() != nil {
        log.Printf("Reading %s stdout error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }

    // Get execution success or failure:
    if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Finished %s", cp[1:])
}
```

Some explanation:

This line:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
```

Creates a [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) that will read from the pipe that supplies the output written by the process.

This line:

```
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
```

Instructs the scanner to read the input by `rune`s instead of the default by-lines.

Note that the above example only streams the standard output of the process. If you also need its standard error stream, you could also read from [`Command.StderrPipe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StderrPipe).

Also note that this won't work with some commands that don't write everything to their standard output or error. For details, see [How to get the realtime output for a shell command in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091316/how-to-get-the-realtime-output-for-a-shell-command-in-golang/37137583#37137583)

Comment: Thanks 1+ , can you see my updates why the output is like this ?

Comment: I think it's becouse of `count, err := stdout.Read(oneRune)` , any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and now I got even worse `2018/02/18 11:44:14 a
2018/02/18 11:44:14 d
2018/02/18 11:44:14 d
2018/02/18 11:44:14 e
2018/02/18 11:44:14 d
2018/02/18 11:44:14  
2018/02/18 11:44:14 5`

Comment: each byte in a new line

Comment: @RaynD Do note when streaming the output I use `fmt.Printf()` and **not** `log.Printf()`.

Comment: Ohh now I see, there is no way to use log? and why it works on fmt and not log?

Comment: @RaynD If it works with `fmt`, can you also try the previous version with `oneRune := make([]byte, utf8.UTFMax)`?

Comment: Sure not checking it

Comment: @RaynD And it works with `fmt` because `fmt.Printf()` does not append a newline to the end, while `log.Printf()` does append a newline.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the `fmt` part , it works and Im closing the question , it will be great if you can provide additaionl info about this 3 lines ,`  `scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
  scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
  oneRune := make([]byte, utf8.UTFMax)` what is utf.UTFMax` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, one last question , assume I need to execute a code when the all process has finished (all the loops is done) where is the best to do it ?

Comment: @RaynD Edited the answer to add more explanation. If you want to run a process once all the processes completed successfully, best would to be to also list that command in the slice of commands to execute (add that to `cmdParams`), and so the loop will also execute that as the last command.

Comment: @RaynD I think I misunderstood, thought you have to run one last command if all other has completed. If you want to run Go code, just put it after the `for` loop, since if any previous command fails, it returns, and then the code after the loop would not be reached.

Comment: @RaynD Please see edited answer. I simplified it as it was overly complicated.