# Running executable on command line is fine, but running through another program causes non-responsiveness

Tags: windows, go, command-line, executable

Running an executable on a Windows command prompt along with the arguments is just fine:

```
cgx_STATIC.exe -b C:\Users\m3\AppData\Local\Temp\shot-277325955.fbd
```

But when running the same executable through Golang, the executable becomes non-responsive after some of the output files are created by the executable.

```golang
// Run an executable and print its log into a file.
func RunWithLogFile(pthExe string, arg []string, fLog *os.File) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(pthExe, arg...)

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Stream logs:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849811/3405291
    scannerOut := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    scannerErr := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
    scannerOut.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    scannerErr.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scannerOut.Scan() {
        _, err = fLog.WriteString(scannerOut.Text())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    for scannerErr.Scan() {
        _, err = fLog.WriteString(scannerErr.Text())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    if scannerOut.Err() != nil {
        return err
    }
    if scannerErr.Err() != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    return err
}
```

I was wondering if the above Go code is somehow buggy or not suitable for running executables?

## Separate goroutines

As suggested by @BurakSerdar I read from stdout and stderr in separate goroutines, but the problem didn't get resolved:

```golang
// Run an executable and print its log into a file.
func RunWithLogFile(pthExe string, arg []string, fLog *os.File) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(pthExe, arg...)

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go streamToLogFile(stdout, fLog, &wg)
    go streamToLogFile(stderr, fLog, &wg)

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    wg.Wait()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    return err
}

func streamToLogFile(output io.ReadCloser, fLog *os.File, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        _, err := fLog.WriteString(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: write to log file: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
    err := scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: write to log file: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be waiting to write to stderr while you're expecting input from stdout. Read fro stdout and stderr in separate goroutines.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Right. The `for` loops look kind of suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-responsiveness was resolved by running the executable with **admin** **privileges**. I am doing this:

```
A C# code runs a Go code and the Go code runs a C Code, i.e. external executable.
```

The C executable calls some OpenGL GLUT calls. Maybe they need **admin privileges**.

The problem was resolved by C# launching the Go code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532775/3405291

```cs
        public static void RunLogic(string exePath, string args, PostProcess pp)
        {
            cmd = new Process();

            try
            {
                cmd.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
                cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                // Vista or higher check.
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532775/3405291
                if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
                {
                    // Run with admin privileges to avoid a non-responsive executable.
                    cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                }
                cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(cmd_Exited);
                cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(pp);

                cmd.Start();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RhinoApp.WriteLine("Error on process start: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The non-responsiveness was resolved by running the executable in batch mode. Studying the [documentation](http://www.dhondt.de/cgx_2.21.pdf):</s>

> But you need a graphic-capable computer because cgx needs it
> even if no graphic output is requested. Nevertheless the pop up of the graphic
> window can be suppressed by starting cgx with the `-bg` parameter. In this
> mode the performance is higher since no graphic related actions are performed.

<s>So, running the executable with `-bg` resolved the problem.</s>

#### UPDATE

The `-bg` parameter skips some features that I need. So, it couldn't help.